# Consuming Api in Console Application

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I'm trying to consume my api using a console application and
I'm getting an exception. When I'm trying to put my JSON data to my model, these are the following exceptions:

> Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in
>   mscorlib.dll Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in
>   mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in
>   ConsoleApplication1.exe

My Source Code:

```
class Program
{
    public class IndividualModel
    {
        public string PayorCode { get; set; }
        public string Adminlvl { get; set; }
        public string LvlDesc { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient cons = new HttpClient();
        cons.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52505/");
        cons.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        cons.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        try
        {
            MyAPIGet(cons).Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            try
            {
                throw e.GetBaseException();
            }
            catch (Exception ea)
            {
                //throw ea.InnerException;
                Console.WriteLine(ea.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task MyAPIGet(HttpClient cons)
    {
        using (cons)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage res = await cons.GetAsync("api/PayorPortal/GetPayorUserLevel?payorCode=STARCAR&adminlvl=1");
            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                IndividualModel tag = await res.Content.ReadAsAsync<IndividualModel>();
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------Calling Get Operation------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine("tagId tagName tagDescription");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t\t{2}", tag.Adminlvl, tag.LvlDesc, tag.PayorCode);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

this is the json data

> "[{\"PayorCode\":\"STARCAR\",\"Adminlvl\":\"1\",\"LvlDesc\":‌​\"Administrator\"},{‌​\"PayorCode\":\"STAR‌​CAR\",\"Adminlvl\":\‌​"2\",\"LvlDesc\":\"S‌​ystem
>   Admin\"},{\"PayorCode\":\"STARCAR\",\"Adminlvl\":\"3\",\"Lvl‌​Desc\":\"System
>   User\"}]"

Comment: Can you share us the JSON data? That'd really help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, this is the json data  "[{\"PayorCode\":\"STARCAR\",\"Adminlvl\":\"1\",\"LvlDesc\":\"Administrator\"},{\"PayorCode\":\"STARCAR\",\"Adminlvl\":\"2\",\"LvlDesc\":\"System Admin\"},{\"PayorCode\":\"STARCAR\",\"Adminlvl\":\"3\",\"LvlDesc\":\"System User\"}]"

Comment: Is this what you're getting in this line: `HttpResponseMessage res = await cons.GetAsync("api/PayorPortal/GetPayorUserLevel?payorCode=STARCAR&adminlvl=1");`?

Comment: No, when that code of line is executed an exception is thrown so i don't really know what is it getting. But when i tried to use var message = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; i got the json string which i just posted :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're getting your JSON data, please check if you're getting a single one or a list. The reason you're getting this `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException` is because your it can't map your JSON data to your Model since you're mapping it to an `IndividualModel`.

My suggestion is you add a breakpoint right after the `GetAsync()` then check if it's a List. If it is, then change this line:

```
IndividualModel tag = await res.Content.ReadAsAsync<IndividualModel>();
```

to this:

```
List<IndividualModel> tag = await res.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<IndividualModel>>();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It worked! My model got the values, but the value of tag is "{ConsoneApplication1.Program.IndividualModel}" but anyways, thank you sir, im going to figure this out on my own. :D Great help!

Comment: You should now call each values like this, tag[0].etc. This is an example:
Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t\t{2}", tag[0].Adminlvl, tag[0].LvlDesc, tag[0].PayorCode);

Comment: Already commented here the solution to that. Upvote the answer, too, fellow filipino :P Awesome name btw. Hahahaha

Comment: yeah my bad i was trying to output it using  tag.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);. Thank youuu!

Comment: i tried upvoting it haha "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 " :( sad